# Unable to render link using react-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

```
const msgid =
  'Not all item(s) could be added to your <a title="Cart" href="http://localhost:4502/homepage.html" target="_blank">Cart</a>. Please review error(s) below. ';
const msg =
  'Not all item(s) could be added to your <a title="Cart" href="http://localhost:4502/homepage.html" target="_blank">Cart</a>. Please review error(s) below. ';

<FormattedMessage id={msgid} defaultMessage={msgid}>
  {data => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }} ></span>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

Version: `"react-intl": "^5.20.13",`

Only text is displayed without the link. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The `id` supposed to be a string of a key instead of a variable. Therefore, to fix your issue, you need to simply update your code with the following

```
<FormattedMessage id={'msgid'} defaultMessage={msg}>
  {(data) => <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }}></span>}
</FormattedMessage>
```

See your code in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-frost-76fsxl?file=/src/App.tsx

Read more about `FormattedMessage` component: https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/components/#formattedmessage

Comment: But the variable has string right?

Comment: check this: `https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-wind-gv9nqd?file=/src/index.js`

Comment: True, but the `id` is supposed to be in a different format how is it on the official doc `id="app.greeting"` instead of a long message-like string. But if it works for you it works for you.

Comment: Seems like you are able to find a fix for the issue, or am i misunderstanding your question?